# How do I find which CCSprite in an array is closest to a given position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I've been trying to create AI for my Enemy class, and I'm having problems updating which Enemy is closest to Player. It works when there's only two enemies but when theres 3 or more thats when I get issues. I only want the closest to attack, but all the enemies except the farthest do. 
I think it's because with three or more sprites one can be in between the others making his position safePosition and attackPosition, but how would I get the middle enemies to realize when any tempEnemy is in front of them?

```
 CCArray *fellowEnemy = [self allyArray];
for (int i = 0; i<[fellowEnemy count]; i++) {
    Enemy *tempEnemy = [fellowEnemy objectAtIndex:i];
    if (tempEnemy == self) continue;
    CGPoint tempDifference = ccpSub(player.position, tempEnemy.position);
    CGPoint selfDifference = ccpSub(player.position, self.position);
    float tempToPlayer = ccpLength(tempDifference);
    float selfToPlayer = ccpLength(selfDifference);

    if (tempToPlayer > selfToPlayer) {
        newPosition = attackPosition;

    }else if (tempToPlayer < selfToPlayer){
        newPosition = safePosition;

    }else{
        newPosition = safePosition;
    }
}

[self setPosition:newPosition];
```

Thank You

Comment: Is your question "How do I find which CCSprite in an array is closest to a given position?"

Comment: Yes, thats what I should have made the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to determine the enemy closest to the player. The one in the middle will always be the closest to the player. So you just gonna have to find out the one which has minimum distance to the player.

```
    CCArray *fellowEnemy = [self allyArray];
    if( fellowEnemy.count > 0 )
    {
        Enemy *closestEnemy = nil;
        float minDistance = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<[fellowEnemy count]; i++) {
            Enemy *tempEnemy = [fellowEnemy objectAtIndex:i];
            if (tempEnemy == self) continue;

            if( closestEnemy == nil )
            {
                closestEnemy = tempEnemy;
                minDistance = ccpDistance(player.position, closestEnemy.position);
                continue;
            }

            float curDistance = ccpDistance(player.position, tempEnemy.position);
            if( curDistance < minDistance )
            {
                minDistance = curDistance;
                closestEnemy = tempEnemy;
            }
        }

        if( closestEnemy != nil )
        {
            // Here you have closest enemy 
            // Write your remaining logic (position, attack... whatever)
        }
    }
```